# Paperclip stub S3 upload but do processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, amazon-s3, paperclip

Our rails code uses paperclip in a lot of situations.
Our Rspec test suite would take forever if not for stubbing out the paperclipping most of the time.

We sometimes want to stub Paperclip completely like this:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.any_instance.stubs(:save).returns(true)
```

sometimes we want to stub away only the processing (thumbnailing), but still see the request to S3; this seems to do the job:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.any_instance.stubs(:post_process)
```

Now I wonder how we could stub just the upload part to S3 but still be able to do processing, so that only a local file is getting used.

Answer (score 2):

I'd configure paperclip to use local filesystem in for tests

```
# config/environments/test.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => <local fs value>,
}
```

It'll allow you not to use S3 in whole test suit

Comment: for those coming here replace <local fs value> with filesystem